# insert float from java application into Oracle Database 11gr2

Tags: java, oracle

While inserting values from `Jtable` into my database I receive this error:

> :java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: Nombre non valide

Here is the major dependencies:

```
String a=(String) (table.getValueAt(j,1));
Float echantillons= Float.parseFloat(a);

int rs=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into testing values ('"+echantillons+"')");
```

```
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ECHANTILLIONS                      NUMBER(10,20)
```

Comment: The problem is solved thanks to "Luke Woodward"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameterised SQL.

As well as being general good practice (get into the habit of using it and you'll avoid SQL injection), it also means you avoid any internationalization issues between Java and Oracle.  Perhaps your issue arises the two systems have different decimal separators (`,` vs `.`).

```
String a=(String) (table.getValueAt(j,1));
Float echantillons= Float.parseFloat(a);

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "insert into testing (echantillions) values (?)");

stmt.setFloat(1, echantillions);
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01722: invalid number

means you are trying to insert a string to number filed ,
do you have access to the source data ?

Answer (score 0):

This `...'"+echantillons+"'...` means you want to insert the value of `echantillons` as a string. But as it is a `NUMBER(10,20)` you probably want:

```
int rs = stmt.executeUpdate(
             "insert into testing (echantillons) values ("+echantillons+")");
```

See omitted `'` above.